# SQL. Консолидация значений строк таблицы в одну

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица:

| id | fdate | s_1 | s_2 | s_3 | s_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | Да |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 |  | Нет |  |  |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 |  |  | Да |  |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 |  |  |  | Да |
| 5 | 2023-01-01 | Да |  |  |  |
| 6 | 2023-01-01 |  | Да |  |  |
| 7 | 2023-01-01 |  |  | Нет |  |
| 8 | 2023-01-01 |  |  |  | Да |

Нужно в запросе вывести:

| id | fdate | s_1 | s_2 | s_3 | s_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | Да | Нет | Да | Да |
| 5 | 2023-01-01 | Да | Да | Нет | Да |

Как такое можно реализовать без применения хранимых процедур?

Comment: А даты там принципиально все одинаковые, или, всё-таки, это кварталы по разным годам? Будут разные решения

Comment: @rotabor даты по крайней мере по-блочно одинаковые. Мало того, сейчас ввели новую вводную: количество столбцов может произвольно меняться, но не меньше 3-х. Т.е. м.б. s_5, s_6 и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Если принять, что дата в строках 5-8 должна быть другая, то решение может быть таким (Table_4 просто случайное название для исходной таблицы):

```
SELECT Table4.fdate, First(Table4.s_1) AS FirstOfs_1, First(Table4_1.s_2) AS FirstOfs_2, First(Table4_2.s_3) AS FirstOfs_3, First(Table4_3.s_4) AS FirstOfs_4
FROM Table4 AS Table4_3 INNER JOIN (Table4 AS Table4_2 INNER JOIN (Table4 AS Table4_1 INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table4_1.fdate = Table4.fdate) ON Table4_2.fdate = Table4.fdate) ON Table4_3.fdate = Table4.fdate
WHERE (((Table4.s_1) Is Not Null) AND ((Table4_1.s_2) Is Not Null) AND ((Table4_2.s_3) Is Not Null) AND ((Table4_3.s_4) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY Table4.fdate;
```

Для произвольного количества столбцов только могу предложить генерировать запрос программно. Можно решить эту задачу с помощью другого запроса, но там тоже требуется явно задавать столбцы. Я не знаю способа работы с произвольным количеством столбцов. Может, специалисты ещё подскажут.

Comment: Спасибо за идею буду думать дальше)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется что-то такое вполне должно сработать, но я не настоящий `SQL`-щик:

```sql
SELECT (CAST((id-1)/4 as INT)*4 + 1) as id, MAX(fdate), MAX(s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4)
GROUP BY 1
```